# How to give the creator of a package / framework some elevated rights?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki, tag-creation

This is a bit of a question with a comment, and a bit of a story. **I'm a bit new to meta and getting some downvotes -- if someone wouldn't mind telling me why, that would be great.**

I just created the [docassemble](/questions/tagged/docassemble) tag (docassemble.org), and apparently the person who actually wrote the library didn't have enough rep to do so.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make "special case" requests for editing the tag wiki for users in similarly important positions (oddly, if I understand, I seem to have enough rep to create the tag but not enough rep to edit the tag wiki). Imagine if Evan You couldn't meaningfully contribute to [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) on SO -- this is I think an analogous situation.

The accepted answer on this tag thread ([When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)) says:

> Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're
> still clearly defined. Make sure to submit at least an excerpt for the
> tag wiki so others can see its intended use.

Which brings me to more clearly defining the two purposes of this post:

1. Is there a way to give special permissions to Evan You - type - people, who might just not have a high SO rep because of the "uncommonness" of their subject area? **I think there's a definite benefit to imbuing such folks with the ability to shepherd their community on SO.**
2. Is it perhaps time for an edit to the description on the above-noted page on how to actually edit the tag wiki? It doesn't actually direct you to the tag wiki edit page, and I found it a headache to find out how to do that... for those that might be looking, you need only go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags, select the tag, and hit up "**help us create it**" which takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/149973. I assume the number at the end of the URL is the tag's id.

Comment: Doing such actions properly still requires a good understanding of how the SE platform works. The only way we can measure such things is by reputation, which unlocks a lot of the privileges you seem to want to award (permissions). I don't think adding exceptions is a good idea.

Comment: @Mast I don't disagree, but I also think that the community might benefit by someone who actually wrote a language / package being able to have some level of direct input into creating / maintaining the community around those items on SO. Obviously every such decision is a judgement call / balancing act and I definitely understand and respect your position.

Comment: Actually, the owners of a product or service behind a tag are sometimes the *worst* people to write tag wikis because they oftentimes tend to write things that read more like advertisements instead of guidance on how to use the tag and what the tag means to the site. I've rolled back many tag wiki edits from owners that just copy-pasted marketing material off their website.

Comment: @animuson That's what I just did for this one (for the longer description anyway). Any tips?

Comment: Creating a tag, which requires 1,500 reputation on non-beta sites, is not something which we want to be giving special access to to users who's first priority is their thing, rather than the site. Any logged-in user can suggest tag wiki and tag excerpt edits, which are then reviewed by users with >= 5k rep. Only once the user gets to >=20k reputation are they given the privilege of editing tag wikis and excerpts without review by other users. I don't see any need for, or benefit from, giving something's primary contributors special access to making changes to tag wikis and excerpts.

Comment: Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although votes can also reflect that. As a consequence, downvotes on Meta should not be considered negative to the person who wrote the post. In the case of this question, I'd assume that all, or at least nearly all, of the downvotes reflect disagreement.

Comment: The person can ask for a new tag to be created, in a comment under their 1st question; which later they can delete. If it's their  first answer and they're the expert they'll soon earn the reputation - not sure what situation you're addressing: let them create a tag with no excerpt (which we dislike), or an excerpt that probably isn't expertly written, by someone familiar with the description's quality standards. --- Even fairly high reputation users have their Tag Wikis proofread; we don't need low rep creators (how should we decide them capable?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Super User (where I'm a moderator), I think we've seen both extremes of developers being active on the site. There's a few primarily focused on *spamming* their site on one end. On the other, there's folks who mainly *answer* questions on their software or better yet, answer either questions adjacent to their subject matter expertise or even questions in general.

*Meta* and *comments* are a reasonable workaround but - if a tag subject is notable enough, we should be relying on our high rep users to organically create it. If a creator or developer has feedback on the tag, we can funnel it through our usual processes.

Reputation is *automatic*. You earn it as you use a site. 'Special' casing developers or maintainers of a software can be complicated. Who decides who to give such rights to? What would be notable enough. Can we manage a developer leaving or forking a project (and what do we do if its a hostile fork?).

There's also the potential for users to request such abilities for less benevolent reasons, and someone has to work out who is who.

As for editing, how much more straightforward does it have to be than having it under the learn more link (where you can read the whole tag wiki?)

[image]

Comment: I agree it's not hard to find the edit tag info... just that the first results on Google are a bit misleading because of that blog post, which implies there is a "wiki" which if you click the links, you'll be taken to.

Comment: The minute a developer gets special rights, without earning the trust of the community, by participating in the community is the day I swear off Stack Exchange communities and throw it into the trash bin along with Quroa.  I despise Quora by the way and take every chance to say it’s complete and utter trash.

Answer (score 9):

Having created some package, tool, technique, or idea does not mean that you know how tagging on Stack Exchange works or even that you are sure that the thing you invented is even on-topic. For that, we need to know that you understand these basic things first by obtaining some rep.